# Authorising Client Routes in a Single Page Application

Tags: node.js, authorization, single-page-application, sammy.js

I'm writing a SPA that uses [SammyJS](http://sammyjs.org/%22SammyJS%22) for the client routing. A user is either authenticated or not, and I would like to filter access to the client routes they can access.

For example, say I have two client routes '#/public' and '#/private'. The user has to login to access '#/private'. The login part works fine, user enters username and password, calls the RESTful API (sitting on NodeJS) and is returned an authentication token. They are then redirected to '#/private'. The obvious problem though is that anyone can call '#/private'.

I was thinking of calling SammyJS before() on the '#/private' route and checking the user is authenticated. Has anyone else tried this approach ?

Comment: see http://sammyjs.org/docs/api/0.7.2/Sammy.Application._methods_.around